# C# ConsoleWriteLine,ReadLine Errors?

Tags: c#

The problem is i cant use all these simple stuff and also i import all these libraries...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;    
using System.Linq;    
using System.Text;    
using System.Threading.Tasks;    
using System.Diagnostics;

public class GainMoney
{

    public int currentMoney = 100;
    public string choose;

    Console.WriteLine("Please Choose What Are You Wanna Produce");
    choose = Console.ReadLine();



    public int addCurrentMoney()
    {
        if ((currentMoney - Farm.costoffarm) > 0)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50000);
            return currentMoney + 10;
        }
        else
        {
            return currentMoney;
        }

    }
}
```

[image: ERROR LIST --->]

Comment: Your class definition is not valid, the Console actions need to be inside of a function

Comment: What you mean _"I cant use"_? Your code will not even compile.

Comment: @SeM :D that is why he has a compile time errors in the image ;-)

Comment: @CodeNotFound Sorry, I can't see images from my workplace, imgur is blocked :)

Comment: Is this a console app? sure you have a console to write to (as well as the fact this code is never valid)

Comment: Please don't post a screenshot that is too small to view, instead post the actual error messages *as text*.

Answer (score 2):

You can't call functions (methods, proeprties, events etc...) on class level.

The following lines:

```
Console.WriteLine("Please Choose What Are You Wanna Produce");
choose = Console.ReadLine();
```

have to be inside a method.

Comment: Actually you can, as long as method will return a value and you will assign it to some variable.

Comment: You can assign results of static methods to class variables.

Comment: @SeM _and you will assign it to something._ Partially true. The OP already does `choose = Console.ReadLine();` but that is not compilng because that is not part of the member declaration. I think

Comment: @CodeNotFound well yes, I'm just commenting about Markus's answer - _"You can't call functions (methods, proeprties, events etc...) on class level."_. :)

Comment: @SeM it depends on what you mean by "call". Here it talk about execution. Also class level means root of the class. Calling functions when defining member is not a class level but member level ;-)

Answer (score 2):

```
Console.WriteLine("Please Choose What Are You Wanna Produce");
```

This statement need to be inside a method for execution. As suggested by @Markus Dresch - "

> You can't call functions (methods, proeprties, events etc...) on class
>   level.

Try to fix your code like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;    
using System.Linq;    
using System.Text;    
using System.Threading.Tasks;    
using System.Diagnostics;

public class GainMoney
{   

    public int currentMoney = 100;
    public string choose;



    public int addCurrentMoney()
    {
        if ((currentMoney - Farm.costoffarm) > 0)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50000);
            return currentMoney + 10;
        }
        else
        {
            return currentMoney;
        }

    }

    public void SomeNewMethod(){
        Console.WriteLine("Please Choose What Are You Wanna Produce");
        choose = Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

As I suppose you have created a Console Application, use the class as follows:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        GainMoney gainMoney = new GainMoney();
        gainMoney.SomeMethod();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should write the lines:

```
Console.WriteLine("Please Choose What Are You Wanna Produce");
choose = Console.ReadLine();
```

into the conctructor of your class, when you want them to be called everytime.

Like:

```
public class GainMoney
 {
    public int currentMoney = 100;
    public string choose;

    public GainMoney()
    {
       Console.WriteLine("Please Choose What Are You Wanna Produce");
       choose = Console.ReadLine();
     }
 }
```

Edit: added access modifier `public` to constructor, typo

Comment: Calling `Console.ReadLine();` inside a constrcutor . I think it is a really bad idea.